# document.getElementById not working in brave settings

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, brave

I am trying to select the dropdown of colours in brave settings. However, the console is not able to select the element.

[image]

It gives `null` when I run the command to select element by id.

[image]

This doesn't happen when I visit any other page on the browser. Only the settings page is giving this error.

An MRE would be running `document.getElementById("braveThemeType")` in developer tools with settings page (*brave://settings/appearance*) open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That select element is inside several nested [shadow doms](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_components/Using_shadow_DOM) on the page.

In order to get a reference to elements inside a shadow dom you need to get a reference to the `shadowRoot` property first and query from there. For example if there was a shadow root on the `<body>` you would need to do

```
document.body.shadowRoot.querySelector('someelement');
```

So in your case the select on the brave settings page you have to go through several nested shadow doms to get the element.

```
const themeSelect = document.querySelector('settings-ui').shadowRoot
    .querySelector('settings-main').shadowRoot
    .querySelector('settings-basic-page').shadowRoot
    .querySelector('[section=appearance] settings-appearance-page').shadowRoot
    .querySelector('settings-animated-pages settings-brave-appearance-theme').shadowRoot
    .querySelector('#braveThemeType')
```